# How to increase hall sensor voltage

Tags: hall-effect

I apologize but I know jack about this stuff and this is probably a simple question I can’t seem to figure out.  I have 12 volt power supply, a 3 wire unipolar Honeywell SRC3-A1 4.5-24 volt hall sensor but only puts out 380-400mv on the supply line and I need it to power a crydom DC60S3 solid state relay that requires min of 3.5-32 volt.  How do I bring up the voltage from .4v to say 5v?  Simplest option preferred for a electricical dummy.

Hall Sensor: https://sensing.honeywell.com/SR3C-A1-value-added-magnetic-sensors

Relay:  http://www.crydom.com/en/products/catalog/dc60-series-dc-panel-mount.pdf

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You need to build or buy an amplifier, similar to a audio pre-amp but it must amplify DC by a factor of ten, maybe twenty. We *could* design you a simple op-amp solution, but your skills may limit you to buy what you need.

Comment: I tried building a op amp circuit then I realized I bought the wrong op amp (LM741) needing the same voltage I was trying to get to and from what I’ve found so far in my reading I believe I may need a single supply op amp which 741 is also not?.  Kinda just winging it and making some sparks n smoke so far...; ) kinda fun and learning, but I do have a mission to accomplish here. I do have some resistors and a board, but can’t seem to find a op amp that fits all the parameters of low input voltage, single supply, etc. but certainly open to suggestions or links to a pre built option as well.

Comment: Well, technically we are not a shopping service per se, but maybe some of the wizards here can come up with a design. The OP220EZ maybe a good choice, but it has low drive current.

Comment: Please add a link (in your question) to the sensor datasheet.

Comment: Thanks Sparky.  Understand not a shopping service and I can find where to buy, just trying to find the right parts to buy.  Maybe I am reading the specs wrong but it appears that the Op220 needs a min 4 volt supply and I have a .4 volt supply.  I can’t seem to find a op amp that goes low enough on the input voltage.

Comment: @LonnyM - "*I can’t seem to find a op amp that goes low enough on the input voltage.*" Now you have provided a link to the sensor's data, it confirmed my suspicion: You're looking for the wrong thing. Stop trying to use an op-amp; it isn't needed. The first step in understanding how to use that sensor, is that its output is *open collector* and the 0.4V value is *not* a voltage for you to amplify. I can't write a full answer including schematic from this phone (and we shouldn't answer in comments {site rule}) so you'll have to wait for someone else to explain in an answer, but that's a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

It should be this simple. Here is why.

The output of the hall device is specified as open collector and is capable of sinking 10ma. The chart of the current demand for the relay says ~7ma at 12 volts. Because the Hall device is open collector, there should be no current when off which is well below the 2.2ma turn on for the relay.

Comment: Oh good lord, that was way easier than I made it...; ).  Oh well works great and I learned a bunch about resistors, op amps, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi LonnyM, Work with ohm's law. This was solved by thinking with current. Voltages are almost irrelevant. Please mark this as answered if you like it.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

*Figure 1. Small loads can be driven directly by the Hall sensor's NPN output.*

Where currents higher than the 10 mA rating of the sensor then use one of the schemes shown on page 2 of the datasheet.

[image]

*Figure 2. (Top) External NPN inverting switch. (Bottom) External PNP non-inverting switch.*

- The upper circuit will be normally on due to the bias provided to the NPN transistor by the 1.2k resistor. When the Hall sensor turns on its output will pull low and steal the bias from the transistor so the load will turn off.
- The lower circuit is off by default. When the Hall sensor switches low it will pull current from the base of the PNP transistor and turn it on.

> ... but only puts out 380-400mv on the supply line ...

No, that specification means that it can pull the output down to 380 - 400 mV (capital V for volt) when it is turned on. This is important in the upper circuit as we need to pull lower than about 0.6 V to turn off the NPN transistor.

The Crydom SSR is a little more sophisticated than my Figure 1 suggests. Rather than a series resistor on the input side it probably has a constant current circuit to drive the required current (probably about 10 mA) through the internal LED. The datasheet should give the actual value.